# Django variable in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm passing a variable `i` from a view to a template. When I'm printing `{{ subject.i.id }}` then it is not working.

```
# the view 
return render_to_response(
         'feedback/feedback.html',
         {'subjects': subject_list, 'n': n, 'list': sub_list, 'i': 0},
         context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 

# the template 
{% for s in list %} 
    <div id="{{ subjects.i.id }}"> 
    {% for subject in s %} 
        <div> {{ subject }} </div> 
    {% endfor %} 
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a template filter for this to work

My template filter for similar case:

```
import re
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

numeric_test = re.compile("^\d+$")
register = template.Library()

def getattribute(value, arg):
    """Gets an attribute of an object dynamically from a string name"""
    if hasattr(value, str(arg)):
            return getattr(value, arg)
    elif hasattr(value, 'has_key') and value.has_key(arg):
            return value[arg]
    elif numeric_test.match(str(arg)) and len(value) > int(arg):
            return value[int(arg)]
    else:
            return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID

register.filter('getattribute', getattribute)


# in the template 
{{ folder_info|getattribute:folder.id }}
```

Comment: Good answer, but this is a filter, not a tag.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, if you attach the code it would be nice. Make sure you render correctly, and the object has its compatible property name

Comment: # the view

return render_to_response('feedback/feedback.html', {'subjects':subject_list,'n':n,'list':sub_list,'i':0},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# the template

{% for s in list%}
                   
                   <div id="{{ subjects.i.id }}">  
                   {% for subject in s%}
                        
                       
                        <div> {{ subject }} </div>    
                       
                       
                   {% endfor %}
                   </div>
             {% endfor %}